# How can I update password for remote GitHub repository

Tags: github, passwords

So for some reason my remote repository password has changed.
Now every time I try to perform any action via my computer (push, pull ect) I'm just getting 403 error.

Does anyone know how I can reset the password that git (I assume) has saved somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS and the version of Git you are using.

For Mac, you might have been using the [OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/).
In that case, use `git credential-osxkeychain erase` in order to reset.

On Windows, try `git config credential.helper store`.
See also "[remove credentials from git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15381198/6309)"

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, it seems none of those methods suggested worked to removed the credentials for me. I'm using Git-hub for Windows.

Here is the exact error I'm encountering
`fatal: unable to access 'https://www.example.com/': The requested URL returned error: 403`

That's not my actual site name up there i just changed it because it was too long.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, had to delete git from appdata to get it to re-ask the password.